# How to run mongodb service in gitlab runner with docker executer

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to establish **pipeline** in **gitlab** for testing my **api** written in **laravel** with **mongodb** as database. Following is my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file.

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/sadhu/web:latest

services:
  - name: mongo:3.4.10

variables:
  MONGO_URI: 'mongodb://mongo/demo'

stages:
  - test

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - composer install
    - cp .env.testing .env
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan config:cache
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

But unit test results in negative results. Following is the result of my unit testing:

```
1) TestBedApiTest::testDuplicateId
Expected status code 409, got 500.
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 409.
```

**500** error mostly comes when laravel api is unable to connect to database. But I'm not sure whether it is the main reason or not and I'm not able to find out, how to ensure this.

Following is my **.env.testing** file.

```
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=base64:fvuqjkl+g7MNIH2eC39Osp78feOfHhMDXPXSlKHlPD4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=mongo
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=demo
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Can someone tell me how to enable mongodb service in gitlab runner?

Comment: From configuration standpoint all looks ok. Can you check the logs?

Comment: @TarunLalwani sir, how to check logs?

Comment: See if this helps https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2119

Comment: @TarunLalwani sir, I enabled it, but it is not showing any error